# Define function from expression

Tags: functions, function-construction, expression-manipulation

I generate expressions such as 
`x[1] x[2] + x[2] x[3]`.

How can I can turn these expressions to functions?

My current code simply returns the above expression and then I 
use different values for x[i]'s to evaluate it. It would be 
much better if I could return a function of x[i]'s instead, for example:

```
f[x[1]_, x[2]_, x[3]_]:= x[1] x[2] + x[2]x[3]
```

Or even better to return a function of an array:

```
f[x_] := x[[1]] x[[2]] + x[[2]] x[[3]]
```

Comment: My first impulse was to do as Carl Woll suggests below, but the second part of your question makes me wonder if you are looking for: f[x_] := Indexed[x, 1] Indexed[x, 2] + Indexed[x, 2] Indexed[x, 3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let:

```
expr = x[1] x[2] + x[2] x[3];
```

Then, you can use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) to inject expr as follows:

```
With[{e = expr}, f[z_] := Block[{x}, x[i_]:=z[[i]]; e]]
```

Example:

```
f[{a,b,c}]
```

> a b + b c

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = x[1] x[2] + x[2] x[3];

Clear[f]

f[x_Symbol] = expr;

f[x] /. {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 2, x[3] -> 3}

(* 8 *)

f[y] /. {y[1] -> 1, y[2] -> 2, y[3] -> 3}

(* 8 *)

z[1] = 1; z[2] = 2; z[3] = 3; f[z]

(* 8 *)
```